# Google Cloud file upload in compute engine virtual machine keeps failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For some reason, I can no longer upload anything to the vm I'm using on Google Cloud compute engine. It was working fine, but all of a sudden it doesn't.

I have tried connecting to the vm instance, and tried multiple browsers. I also went in to another project I'm involved in and was able to upload files without issue. The issue is also specific to me because someone else in the project is also able to upload files.

Files are uploaded to the /home/ama542blake directory, and at one point I accidentally moved the directory that shares the name with my username to another directory. It was empty, so I just deleted it and recreated it. My guess is that this may have something to do with it.

When it fails, it gives no indication of why it fails.

So what can I do to remedy the situation?

[Box that pops up on attempted  upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbX0Y.png)

Comment: Use the CLI `gcloud compute scp` command. You will then receive informative error messages. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp

Comment: What specific command / recipe are you using to upload your files?  From what environment are your executing the upload?  Is it SCP, FTP, or something else?

Comment: @JohnHanley ok, I have tried this, and I don't understand the error. I also checked another source of documentation on this and I don't see what's wrong with what this command. gcloud compute scp /Users/Blake/Documents/School/Senior/DatabaseProject/index.php main, where main in the name of my vm instance. Then I get this error.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Source(s) must be remote when destination is local.  Got sources: [/Users/Blake/Documents/School/Senior/DatabaseProject/index.php], 
destination: main

Comment: You have the command syntax wrong. Reread the documentation and follow the examples.